# Reading a file, write to diffrent table if (streamwriter =...)

Tags: c#, datatable, streamreader

I've got a little problem with readin file to datagridviews (3 to be more specific).

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fn))
{
    string[] datarow; int tableno=0;
    colt = sr.ReadLine();
    Console.Out.WriteLine(colt);

    if (colt == "@Table")
    {
        tableno++;//Here tableno is equals 1
        colt = sr.ReadLine();
       // Console.Out.WriteLine(colt);
       // Console.Out.WriteLine(tableno);
    }

    switch (tableno)
    {
      case 1:

                 columns = colt.Split(';');
    Count = columns.Length;

    foreach (string c in columns)
    {
        Table1.Columns.Add(c, typeof(String));
    }

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {

        rowt = sr.ReadLine();
        if (rowt == "@Table") break; //Here program supposed to break this case, go up and increase tableno
        datarow = rowt.Split(';');
        Table1.Rows.Add(datarow);

    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Table1;
    sr.Close();

            break;


        case 2:

                columns = colt.Split(';');
    Count = columns.Length;

    foreach (string c in columns)
    {
        Table2.Columns.Add(c, typeof(String));
    }

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        rowt = sr.ReadLine();
        if (rowt == "@Table") break;
        datarow = rowt.Split(';');
        Table2.Rows.Add(datarow);
    }
    dataGridView2.DataSource = Table2;
    sr.Close();
            break;


        case 3:

                 columns = colt.Split(';');
    Count = columns.Length;

    foreach (string c in columns)
    {
        Table3.Columns.Add(c, typeof(String));
    }

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        rowt = sr.ReadLine();
        if (rowt == "@Table") break;
        datarow = rowt.Split(';');
        Table3.Rows.Add(datarow);
    }
    dataGridView3.DataSource = Table3;
    sr.Close();

            break;
}
}
}
```

My text file is looking like:

```
@Table
K1;K2;K3
....
..
@Table
K1;K4
..
..
@Table
K1;K5
```

and after running this code, data is only appearing in gridview1. Variable tableno didn't want to increase. Someone have an idea?

Comment: Can you try to correctly indent your code. It got a little bit scrambled on the copy-paste I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your existing code work by creating a while loop inside the `using` scope for the `StreamReader`, and stop closing the reader after completing a table table (the reader will be closed for you by the `using` statement, so this is unnecessary anyway). The problem at the moment is that where you see the start of the next table or the end of old one (different in your answer and question..) you break out of the reading loop for that table, but then there's nothing to change the flow to "go up" and start working on the next one, it'll just exit the method at that point.

However, you should more fundamentally change your approach as it's very repetitive. At the moment you've got 3 tables, but what if you had N tables? It's bad practice to repeat code, from a maintenance, testing and extensibility perspective. If the format of your file changes for example, you're going to have to change it in 3 places, and test 3 times as much as if you'd just written it once.

Here's an example of how you could write it to handle any number of tables and re-use the same logic to read each table:

```
private List<DataTable> ReadDataTables(string fileName)
{
    List<DataTable> tables = new List<DataTable>();
    DataTable currentTable = null;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {   
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {                    
            var currentLine = reader.ReadLine(); // get the next line from the file
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentLine)) continue; // ignore blank rows

            // skip rows marking end of table, reset the current table
            if (currentLine.StartsWith("@EndTable", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                currentTable = null;
                continue;
            }

            // initialize a new table
            if (currentLine.StartsWith("@Table", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                currentTable = new DataTable();
                tables.Add(currentTable); 

                // initialise the columns
                var columns = reader.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                foreach (var column in columns)
                    currentTable.Columns.Add(column, typeof(String));

                continue;
            }

            if (currentTable == null) continue; // file is not in the format we were expecting

            // add data row
            var dataRow = currentTable.NewRow();
            dataRow.ItemArray = currentLine.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            currentTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
    }

    return tables;
}
```

You could then use this from your button click event handler as follows;

```
var tables = ReadDataTables(fileName);
dataGridView1.DataSource = tables[0];
dataGridView2.DataSource = tables[1];
dataGridView3.DataSource = tables[2];
```

Comment: Damn thats good. Thanks:)

And for end another problem... i have this variable:

var tables = new DataTable[4] { Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4 };
and im using it in merging table function. This function require that all tables in variable have primary key column.
but there could be a situation that i'm only using f.e.: Table1 and table2.
How can i edit this variable (without errors which i get when amount of tables doesnt match) so i could add or remove objects there?

Comment: It might be better to ask another question as it doesn't sound related and it's not that clear doing it in a comment. I'm not sure if it's what you're asking but you could create a new array like `var tablesWithPrimaryKeys = tables.Where(a => a.PrimaryKey.Any()).ToArray()` to select only the tables that have a primary key.